# Writing a function for a single line of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am currently working with a pandas DataFrame and came across a problem. Should there be a separate function for setting the index or does it make the code to complex since you could simply write the one line of code anyway.

```
def set_time_as_index(df):
    return df.set_index('time')
```

Simplified version of current code:

```
def create_df_rdy_for_export(input_data):
    dframe = pd.DataFrame(input_data)
    dframe = set_time_as_index(dframe)
    return dframe
```

Or is it better to write:

```
def create_df_rdy_for_export(input_data):
    dframe = pd.DataFrame(input_data)
    dframe = dframe.set_index('time')
    return dframe
```

I am simply setting the index to the *time*-column. And since it only appears only one time in the script, there is no need to write a separate function but I am so used to it, that it feels odd, without a function. 
Are there any conventions or performance trade-offs?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, whenever you reuse the same line of code more than once, it can be wise to make it a function. Imagine if you made a mistake or want to change its logic in the future: it's easier if you refactored it as a function. If it only appears once, then it is indeed unecessary.

Comment: This might be a better question for the software engineering stack exchange

Comment: In your example, the code with the function call would be **longer** than writing out the content of the function directly. Not even thinking about reusability and ease of maintainance, this would always be a reason for me *not* to use an extra function.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an opinion-based question, but one I will answer because there are conventions when working with Pandas dataframes.

A common practice is to **chain operations**. You can simply apply methods sequentially. For example (adding an extra method for clarity):

```
def create_df_rdy_for_export(input_data):
    dframe = pd.DataFrame(input_data)\
               .set_index('time')\
               .set_axis(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], axis=1)
    return dframe
```

Each line represents a distinct method. In my opinion, there's no need to write a *separate function* to call a single method. For more complex dataframe manipulations you can use [**`pd.DataFrame.pipe`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html). For example:

```
def format_dataframe(df):
    df = df.set_index('time')\
           .set_axis(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], axis=1)
    return df

def create_df_rdy_for_export(input_data):
    dframe = pd.DataFrame(input_data).pipe(format_dataframe)
    return dframe
```

The benefit here is you can reuse just the manipulation part of your logic for other uses, and `pipe` still allows you to chain additional methods.

Comment: Good to know. I forgot about chaining operations together. And pipe might be useful in the future, first time I took notice of it. 
Thanks ;)